# How to set an expiration date for an html link

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm not sure if I'm being a complete noob at this (it's been a looooong night :D), but is it possible to cache links with .htaccess? I know that you can set extensions and stuff like jpg, png, css, js, etc.

And if you've ever hosted a website, I'm sure you've probably used one of those online "website optimizers", and I keep getting the message "The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:" 
...followed by a list of outside links like Facebook and Google.

Any ideas?

Comment: But what is the type/encoding for a link? URL/html? Link/html? A/html?

Comment: My previous comment was irrelevant. As you can't control caching of external resources the best you can do (in terms of cache control) is not to use them on your site. But it seems like you've been hit by a scam, so I'd recommend use another "optimizer" or hire a specialist.

Comment: Hmm, okay. It doesn't at all seem like a scam (all 3, and they aren't asking for money or any other type of profit), but if it doesn't slow down my website loading significantly (relative to what a website load should take), then I'll just ignore it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, loading scripts from external resources could degrade overall performance. How do you use those links?

Comment: It's mainly Google Translate's API and Facebook's Page widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter the headers or the content for external resources like Google cdn or facebook. Assume that big companies like Google and Facebook know how to cache and what resources are viable to cache and for how long.

For resources on your own server, you can set the `Cache-Control` header with a custom time to  tell the client for how long the page can be cached.

```
<FilesMatch \.(css|js)$>
   Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform, max-age=600"
</FilesMatch>
```

You can check how long it takes to load certain resources on your page by going to your browser and opening the developer console. Under the network tab you can see all requests that are being made. Make sure to load the page both with cache and without cache.